# comment reply by email

Tags: comments, email

Is it possible that the admin replies to a comment by email, replying to the notification message he receives about the comment? And for a whatever user if the subscribe to comments plugin is installed?

In other words, I'm asking if the feature described in section "Comment reply via email" on page http://en.support.wordpress.com/comment-notification-email/ is available for a self hosting blog.